# Do Chrome Browser Extensions need to use hashed file names for cache busting?

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-extension

I'm unable to find a clear answer (or any answer) on this. I'm building a Chrome Extension and using Webpack to package it up.

When building the files, should the names be hashed as with builds for regular websites, or is this not needed?

Put another way, when an extension is updated by the developer in the Google Chrome Store and that update is received by clients who are using the extension, will their cache be busted automatically?

Comment: Not needed. Caching isn't used for extension files.

Comment: Can you point me to a source on that info. I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Comment: See https://crbug.com/1062523 and inspect requests in devtools network panel when opening any extension page. They're not really served, but rather provided in the same way as any local file:// thing.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for this.